# Spy module.exports functions with sinon in NodeJS always returning 0

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon

I am trying to track the number of calls to another function using a test case written with Sinon. I have the following code, and on running the test, the `calledFuncSpy` callCount always gets me 0, which is not expected. Meanwhile, running another spy on `console.log` gives me the correct output, and I have left it commented in the code. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Here’s the code. Let me know if more information is required to solve this problem.

**specs/mymodule.js**

```
const mymodule = require("../src/mymodule.js");
var sinon = require("sinon");
const assert = require("assert");



describe("Test suite", function() {
  let calledFuncSpy;
  let consoleSpy;

  beforeEach(function () {
    calledFuncSpy = sinon.spy(mymodule, "calledFunc");
    consoleSpy = sinon.spy(console, "log");
  })
  afterEach(function () {
    calledFuncSpy.restore();
    consoleSpy.restore();
  })

  it("Test the add method", function () {
    mymodule.ownHelloWorld();
    assert.deepStrictEqual(calledFuncSpy.callCount, 1);
    // assert.deepStrictEqual(consoleSpy.callCount, 1);
  });
})
```

**src/mymodule.js**

```
function ownHelloWorld() {
  calledFunc();
}

function calledFunc() {
  console.log("Hello world");
}

module.exports = {
  ownHelloWorld,
  calledFunc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`calledFunc` called inside `ownHelloWorld` function can NOT be stubbed. It will always use the original `calledFunc` function. `sinon.spy(mymodule, "calledFunc")` can NOT modify the reference of it when calling the `ownHelloWorld` function. Also, see this [comment](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1684#issuecomment-364642677)

You can refactor it like this:

`mymodule.js`:

```js
function ownHelloWorld() {
  module.exports.calledFunc();
}

function calledFunc() {
  console.log('Hello world');
}

module.exports = {
  ownHelloWorld,
  calledFunc,
};
```

`mymodule.test.js`:

```js
const mymodule = require('./mymodule');
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Test suite', function () {
  let calledFuncSpy;
  let consoleSpy;

  beforeEach(function () {
    calledFuncSpy = sinon.spy(mymodule, 'calledFunc');
    consoleSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
  });
  afterEach(function () {
    calledFuncSpy.restore();
    consoleSpy.restore();
  });

  it('Test the add method', function () {
    mymodule.ownHelloWorld();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(calledFuncSpy);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  Test suite
Hello world
    ✓ Test the add method


  1 passing (5ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 mymodule.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```